# "Keep in low gear" driving a gearless electric vehicle

Tags: engine, gears, braking, electric-vehicle

> Note: Don't know if the question is an adequate fit for this site.

If I see a traffic sign telling me to "Keep in low gear" like the [TRAVE COM O MOTOR | Keep in low gear](https://www.google.pt/maps/@40.6555081,-8.3622461,3a,41.4y,245.28h,85.37t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sJYvmXRH-H0uLJka24R9Z2A!2e0!7i13312!8i6656!5m1!1e4) I saw on a Portuguese highway, how can I do it if I drive an electric gearless vehicle, like, for example, a Tesla?

> Note: "Trave com o motor" means "Break using the engine|motor" as Portuguese does not have separate words for engine and motor.

Comment: I think the obvious thing is, you dont. Secondarily, is the sign a requirement or a suggestion?

Comment: @dlu: You completely missed the point on your last edit, so I did a rollback. The main point of my question is the fact the driver does not have gears nor any other means of breaking using the engine|motor!

Comment: Sergiol - @Paulsters comment is correct here. A) you don't have gears. B) electric cars are quite different to ones with internal combustion engines. You already get regenerative braking, so your comment there is an incorrect assumption.

Comment: @RoryAlsop AFAIK, regenerative braking is not breaking using the engine. What regenerative braking does is to get energy of braking into the battery. And yes, you can talk me about the servo brake, but a geared combustion car also has it, so make use of it it is not the goal of that road sign!

Comment: Remember, electric cars aren't all that common yet so there are lots of quirks still to be worked out. Some will be worked out in advance, others only as they become issues.

Comment: Sergiol - the important thing is changing kinetic energy into potential energy. Doesn't matter whether it's flywheel, generator or whatever. It's the equivalent of engine braking

Comment: @sergiol, sorry about the bad edit. I was trying to restate the question to be about the technology to keep it open. Questions about driving technique are off-topic, but it seems like the understanding of the principles involved would still be of interest – and would answer the technique question. Questions of how to deal with the law are a whole 'nother can of worms...

Answer (score 7):

Electric vehicles can "engine" brake by using the drive motors as generators. As they generate electricity they consume the car's potential energy - either from speed or elevation or both. The energy can be used to recharge the battery or dissipated as heat. The changeover between power and regenerative (dynamic) braking is usually handled automatically. So in this case I wouldn't expect you'd have to do anything.